# Python eve - POST a list media files with curl command failed with 422 error

Tags: python, list, curl, media, eve

I use python-eve to build my RESTful API, I set a endpoint 'risks' in settings.py, like so:

```
risks = {
    'schema': {
        'description': {
            'type': 'string',
            'required': True,
        },
        'pic': {
            'type': 'list',
            'schema': {
                'type': 'media',
            }
        },
    }
}
```

I try curl command to POST two jpg files to 'pic' field like so:

```
curl -F "description=something" -F "pic=@test1.jpg,test2.jpg" http://127.0.0.1:8080/risks
```

but get 422 error like this:

```
{"_status": "ERR", "_issues": {"pic": "must be of list type"}, "_error": {"message": "Insertion failure: 1 document(s) contain(s) error(s)", "code": 422}}%
```

what can I do, I tried just one media(not list type),It's no problem,why?
Can someone help me?

Comment: Maybe let us see a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

When you access the `risks` endpoint you need to supply the right datatypes in order for the resource endpoint to work. It complains about the pic you send because that is still a string and not a list.

You can make your life a bit easier by using `requests`

```
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/risks'
data = {description : 'something', 'pic' : ['a','b','c','d']}
r = requests.post(url, json=data)
```

Comment: It helps for me, because I've used `data` parameter for `requests` and it failed with my dictionary. Replacing `data` with `json` fixed my 422 error

Answer (score 0):

> @Mike Tung
>
> ...
>
> You can make your life a bit easier by using requests
>
> ...

**How do you pass files to the requests `json` kwarg ? As file handles ? Or Strings ?**

When I try this,

```
import requests
url = 'http://localhost:5000/tests'
data = {
    'icons': [
        open('/home/test/git-projects/test.com/backend/fixtures/media/test1.jpg').read(), #  If I pass the handle, it fails as well.
        open('/home/test/git-projects/test.com/backend/fixtures/media/test2.jpg').read()
    ]
}
r = requests.post(url, json=data)

/home/test/venvs/test/bin/python2.7 /home/test/git-projects/test.com/backend/__main__.py
    /home/test/venvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/exthook.py:71: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.pymongo is deprecated, use flask_pymongo instead.
      .format(x=modname), ExtDeprecationWarning
    /home/test/venvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/exthook.py:71: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.sentinel is deprecated, use flask_sentinel instead.
      .format(x=modname), ExtDeprecationWarning
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/test/git-projects/test.com/backend/__main__.py", line 43, in <module>
        r = requests.post(url, json=data)
      File "/home/test/venvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 109, in post
        return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
      File "/home/test/venvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
        response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
      File "/home/test/venvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 451, in request
        prep = self.prepare_request(req)
      File "/home/test/venvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 382, in prepare_request
        hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
      File "/home/test/venvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 307, in prepare
        self.prepare_body(data, files, json)
      File "/home/test/venvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 428, in prepare_body
        body = json_dumps(json)
      File "/home/test/venvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 380, in dumps
        return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
      File "/home/test/venvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simplejson/encoder.py", line 275, in encode
        chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
      File "/home/test/venvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simplejson/encoder.py", line 357, in iterencode
        return _iterencode(o, 0)
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

    Process finished with exit code 1
```